# MySQL delete and then select query

Tags: mysql, express

So I have a table called messages, which stores chat messages. I want each message to lasts 24 hours only just like Snapchat. Currently, I first delete all the messages that are past 24 hours and then do a select statement. Is there any other appropriate solution for this?

Pseudocode:

1. DELETE FROM messages WHERE time < cur_date - 24 hours;
2. SELECT * FROM messages;

Comment: How much simpler could it be? You can't do it in a single query.

Comment: You could use the Event Scheduler to do the deletes periodically instead of when you're selecting.

Comment: @Barmar Event scheduler runs over a period of time? If so, then the deletion of the messages is not consistent right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE created_at >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND deleted_at IS NULL;
```

Then delete the messages on a daily or weekly basis if you really don't want to have them in the database. If you want to keep record of these messages, you can simply soft delete them:

```
UPDATE messages SET deleted_at = NOW() WHERE created_at < now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

There is no need to delete the messages before executing the SELECT query.